# Kafka consumer to rest Api

Tags: c#, .net, api, rest, apache-kafka

I'm consuming Kafka events from Azure Event Hub.
After consuming an event, I must call a rest api for each message.
My web api take too much time because of the quantity of informations I should treat(3 to 5 seconds).
How I can call rest api after message consuming without breaking my consumer.
What is the best architecture I should implement (rest api as a background services?? Or any other solutions...)
Im using. Net confluent.Kafka.

Thx.

Comment: You can use Azure functions... you just need to trigger the Azure function and let it do it's job... Your consumer will just trigger the function (azure function will call the rest API) and move to the next message... I  assume here that you are not worrying about the API response in the consumer...

Comment: I don't have access to the Azure Event Hub, I just implement the consumer in my project.is there any other solution please.

Comment: Does your consumer break? How does it break?

Comment: What do you mean you don't have access to Event Hub? You said you're consuming from it. If you mean Azure functions dashboard, then talk to the person who setup the Azure environment to enable Functions because that's basically what they're built for - triggering external actions on events (such as those from Event Hubs). Otherwise, Kafka really doesn't care about the processing time as long as you appropriately adjust the timeouts (please edit your question to include the consumer code)

Comment: I have only the consuming parameters, i don't have access to Azure Event Hub Area. I use the basic Web Apps : https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/tree/master/examples/Web . And i want to call my external WebApi on Line 60 in RequestTimeConsumer.cs class